# tape up, tape down, taped off

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

The rough edges of the hole on the wooden wall were **taped down** in order to prevent splinters of wood to hurt your hand.

Do you say taped down, taped up, taped off, or just taped? I don't know, but I am not sure what's appropriate here.

Imagine someone taping the rough edges of a hole dug into a wall to avoid people hurting themselves when they put their arms inside of it. By taping, I mean applying a tape.

Comment: I do not recognise this use of the phrase _tapped down_, the OED does not contain it, and the GLoWBe corpus has only 6 instanced of _tapped down_, none of them with this meaning. I would say [_sanded_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandpaper), or _smoothed_.

Comment: This doesn't sound like common English. Do you maybe mean "taped down?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Down* can be used phrasally/adverbially to indicate the intent/effect is to prevent the object from moving--especially if the context involves the verbs or meanings of *tie*, *strap*, *tape*, *bind*, *bundle*, etc.

Likely the most common example is *tie down* - if you *tie down the boards on the truck* - we expect the boards won't be moving when the truck does.  Similarly, *taping* something *down* means we don't want what we are taping to move.

*Up* in these contexts will mean to get a bunch of X and keep it bundled.  So if you *tape up X* or *tie up X* - you are trying to prevent X from falling apart or get separated.  If X is a person, animal, or something that can move by itself, you are more concerned with not allowing X to escape, but they might still be able to move somewhat.

*Off* means to separate a portion of X from another portion.  So you might *tape off a wall* to prevent paint from getting on one part of the wall, or *tie off* a thread while sewing to separate the part on the stitch from the dangling thread.

Without *down*, *up*, or *off* - unless context is strong, you're being vague.  Examples: If you *taped* a wall as opposed to *taped off* a wall, it means you literally just put tape on the middle of the wall and the listener/reader will be wondering why.  If you *tied* some boards on a truck - did you slap a string around each board for some reason?

---

> The rough edges of the hole on the wooden wall were taped down in order to prevent splinters of wood to hurt your hand.

Here, I would use *taped over* - because *over* specifically means "to cover."  But honestly if the edges are really scraggly and splintery and the holes are large, then *taped down* would work too.

Comment: ...And it should be 'to prevent [them] _from hurting_ your hand'.

Comment: Hmm, this is really helpful.